# Python - Merge dataframe name contains in list

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframe (for now I am saying 2 but we can have n number of dataframe). And the name of the dataframe is in a list. I want to join all the dataframe whose names are present in the list

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = [['Alex',10],['Bob',12],['Clarke',13]]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['Name','Age'])

data2 = [['David',10],['Alain',12],['Rob',13]]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['Name','Age'])

list = ['df1','df2']                   

# i want something to work like

df3 = pd.Concat(list)
```

Thanks for the help on this.

Comment: just a for loop to iterate over the list will do?

Comment: does it have to be `list = ['df1','df2']` or could it be `list = [df1,df2]`?

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the name as index then do `concat`

```
list = [df1,df2] 

pd.concat([x.set_index('Name') for x in list],axis=1)
Out[270]: 
         Age   Age
Alain    NaN  12.0
Alex    10.0   NaN
Bob     12.0   NaN
Clarke  13.0   NaN
David    NaN  10.0
Rob      NaN  13.0
```

Or using `reduce` + `merge`

```
from functools import reduce
df = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['Name'],
                                            how='outer'), list)
df
Out[275]: 
     Name  Age_x  Age_y
0    Alex   10.0    NaN
1     Bob   12.0    NaN
2  Clarke   13.0    NaN
3   David    NaN   10.0
4   Alain    NaN   12.0
5     Rob    NaN   13.0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) the results use:

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

#     Name  Age
#0    Alex   10
#1     Bob   12
#2  Clarke   13
#3   David   10
#4   Alain   12
#5     Rob   13
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use variable names as `list`. Iterate over the list to get the instance of dataframe and then do the concatenation

```
lis = ['df1','df2']                   

df3 = pd.concat([globals()[i] for i in lis]) # to get instance of df1 from string 'df1'
df3
```

Output

```
Name    Age
Alex    10
Bob     12
Clarke  13
David   10
Alain   12
Rob     13
```